# code for commutative diagrams

Tags: diagrams

There are some diagrams which are little bit complicated, I use array package to draw basic ones I mean square ones. but is it possible to draw any diagram by [array] package?
for example [image]
can you help me in this, thin i can mimic the same way
Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you post  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, but I just noticed that although your questions have received several answers and you have up-voted them, you still haven't accepted any (up-voting and accepting are two different actions). Please revisit your questions and, for each one, consider accepting the answer that best solved your problems; in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: bec i accept all of them :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A rather nice diagram is obtained with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2.5pc,row sep=2pc]
{} & B \arrow{d} \arrow[bend left]{dddrr} \\
A \arrow{r} \arrow{rrd} \arrow[bend right]{rrrdd} & G \\
{} & {} & P \arrow{ul}[swap]{\tilde{\varphi}} \\
{} & {} & {} & B*C \arrow{ul}[swap]{\nu}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot ..how did you know that i need phi with hat? :)

Comment: @Rahman That was a guess. It's a tilde, by the way. If you want a hat, use `\hat{\varphi}` (always in math mode).

Answer (score 2):

You could try the xypic package. See this [page](http://www.tug.org/applications/Xy-pic/) for manuals and documentation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2):

Or else using the [`tikz`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz) `positioning` library

[image: screenshot]

Here's the code:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% arrows set as stealth fighters
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % setup the nodes
    \node (B){$B$};
    \node[below=of B](G){$G$};
    \node[left=of G](A){$A$};
    \node[below right=of G](P){$P$};
    \node[below right=of P](BstarC){$B*C$};
    % connect them
    \foreach \start/\finish/\mylabel in {B/G/, A/G/, A/P/, P/G/$\tilde{\varphi}$, BstarC/P/$\nu$}
    {
        \draw[->](\start)--(\finish) node[midway,above]{\mylabel};
    }
    % bended arrows
    \draw[->](A) to[bend right=30] (BstarC);
    \draw[->](BstarC) to[bend right=20] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```